# How to use a makefile across multiple folders in C++

Tags: c++, makefile, directory

I have a fairly large program, so I am using a makefile to compile the program. However, I would like to separate parts of the program into different folders instead of having the whole program in one folder.

```
Root folder with makefile and other folders
    Folder inside of root folder with files
```

Basically I have one program across multiple files that I would like to compile into one executable. I don't know how to add this all to a makefile so if someone could please explain this to me I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You want to build an executable. You have the source files (e.g. `foo.cc`) in different folders. Do you want to build the object files (e.g. `foo.o`) as an intermediate step? If so, where do you want to put them? In one common folder (e.g. `objects/`) or in the folders where their respective sources are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could could make the root makefile call the makefiles inside the folders.

Example:

```
# The list of your directories under the root directory:
SUBDIRS := foo bar baz

.PHONY: build all test subdirs $(SUBDIRS)

.SUFFIXES:

all: subdirs

subdirs: $(SUBDIRS)

# for each sub directory, do "make -C the_directory"
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@

clean:
        @$(foreach dir,$(SUBDIRS),$(MAKE) -C$(dir) clean;)
```

Your `all` targets inside the subfolders could then call the make files on the next level of subfolders as well as building actual targets if you'd like.